# Google cloud spanner do a full table scan regardless of the definced index

Tags: database, indexing, google-cloud-spanner

it looks like the optimizer is doing table scan instead of index scan if I select columns that are not part of the index!.

I created the following table and index

```
CREATE TABLE customer_lastseen_products (
 customer_ref_value STRING(50) NOT NULL,
 customer_ref_type STRING(20) NOT NULL,
 sku_config STRING(40) NOT NULL,
 mp_code STRING(20) NOT NULL,
 is_added_to_cart BOOL NOT NULL,
 is_purchased BOOL NOT NULL,
l ast_visit_time TIMESTAMP OPTIONS( allow_commit_timestamp = true)
)PRIMARY KEY(customer_ref_value, sku_config),
ROW DELETION POLICY (OLDER_THAN(last_visit_time, INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

and index

```
CREATE INDEX customercodeIndex3 ON customer_lastseen_products(customer_ref_value, customer_ref_type, mp_code, last_visit_time DESC);
```

But this query is doing full table scan

```
SELECT
sku_config , is_added_to_cart, is_purchased
FROM customer_lastseen_products
WHERE(customer_ref_value, customer_ref_type) in (('0f2e9ed9-2d5e-4c78-b03f-0c6dd3f65598', 'customer_code'), ('', 'visitor_id'))
AND mp_code = "mp"
AND last_visit_time between '2020-10-03T12:35:59' and '2022-10-03T12:35:59'
order by last_visit_time desc
```

Comment: Hi, Omar! Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

According to internal documentation, it is encouraged to use the directive `FORCE_INDEX` in order to improve the consistency of queries by specifying the index you would like to use. To add on that, I was able to observe that the Cloud Spanner's query optimizer may take up to 3 days to start using an index after it's creation, as it requires time to collect the database's statistics.

Please find the [documentation article here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#index-directive).